# Cassandra Statement set KeySpace

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Using Cassandra 2.2.8 with 3.0 Connector.
I am trying to create a Statement with QueryBuilder. When I execute Statement it complains **no keyspace defined**. The only way I know to set keyspace is as below (There is no setKeyspace method in Statement). When I do a getKeySpace - I actually get null

```
 Statement s = QueryBuilder.select().all()
            .from("test.tests")
System.out.println("getKeyspace:"+ s.getKeyspace()); >> null
```

Am I doing something wrong, Is there any other (more reliable) way to setKeyspace?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`from(String)`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.Builder.html#from-java.lang.String-) expects a table name.  While what you are doing is technically valid and cassandra will interpret it correctly, the driver is not able to derive the keyspace name in this way.

Instead you could use [`from(String, String)`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.Builder.html#from-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which takes the first parameter as the keyspace.

```java
    Statement s = QueryBuilder.select().all()
            .from("test", "tests");
    System.out.println("getKeyspace:" + s.getKeyspace()); // >> test
```

Comment: yes this worked from("test", "tests"). My other syntax did not work at all.